# How to execute javascript code before php code in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a WooCommerce plugin,

How to execute javascript code (wait to finish it), get a value from a method and use the variable in php code using Wordpress and WooCommerce?

Everything, after call submit payment button.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Just save it in a cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  createCookie("height", $(window).height(), "10");
});

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  }
  else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

And then read it with PHP:

```
<?PHP
   $_COOKIE["height"];
?>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)